# How to handle credentials in an open source project

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, credentials

I have developed an application that lives in a public Github repository.

The app interacts with systems that require credentials that are currently stored in a properties file.

A jenkins box runs the app periodically.

The problem of saving the project in github without exposing my credentials is succinctly addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752752/good-way-to-develop-open-source-without-exposing-credentials).

How do I pass my credentials to the jenkins job without exposing the credentials (needed by the app) to my workmates?

Comment: Shouldn't jenkins have his own credentials?

Comment: @Absurd-Mind. I want to pass e.g the jenkins github credentials to the application.

Comment: maybe deploy keys solve your problem? see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5212358/562363)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I went for a jenkins parametrized build that allowed me to provide string and password type of params.

The params are read in the program via system.getProperty